# Why is the drop-down menu appearing at the top?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Our OOP final project is to create a library "database". Irrelevant details aside, I want to create a drop-down menu for the genre entry rather than have the user enter them manually (more organized database-wise.) I am using tkinter. Clarification: this frame is in a class of its own so I can pack it onto the main window easily.

```
# Set the menu initially
self.menu = StringVar()
self.menu.set("Select Genre ...")
# Create a dropdown menu
self.genre_drop = OptionMenu(window, self.menu,
                             "Fantasy", "Science Fiction", "Horror", "Mystery", "Romance", "Nonfiction")

# Packing the widgets in order of appearance
self.notice.pack(pady=15)
self.title_label.pack()
self.title.pack()
self.genre_label.pack()
self.genre_drop.pack()
self.isbn_label.pack()
self.isbn.pack()
```

Thank you in advance!

[screenshot of tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH5oz.png)

Even though I packed the drop-down after the label, the drop-down is appearing at the top of the frame, before anything else (haven't attached the entire source code because it's 126 lines, but if you need it I'll add it I guess.) What do I do?

Edit: added the beginning of the class. "window" is passed as an argument from the main and is a simple Tk() window.

```
class AddBook:

    # This starts once the class is called
    def __init__(self, window):
        # Frame details
        self.add_book = Frame(window, width=400, height=500)
```

Comment: Are all of these widgets children of `window`? There's not enough code here to tell how your application is structured, *but* I'd suggest making sure `self.genre_drop` has the same master as the other widgets. Perhaps try `self.genre_drop = OptionMenu(self, ...` instead of `self.genre_drop = OptionMenu(window, ...`?

Comment: Yes please add the whole code. It feels like there's an issue somewhere else.

Comment: @TheMyth: No, we don't need the whole code. We need a [mcve]. This problem can be reproduced down to maybe a dozen or two lines of code. We don't need a dozen widgets below the option menu. An example with just one widget below the option menu should be enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I added the beginning of the class if it helps. the rest of the code is just widgets (labels and entries and 2 buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost certainly because you've made the option menu a child of the root window, either intentionally or by accident, but the other widgets are the child of a frame.

Comment: I feel so stupid now pfft! Thank you very much; it worked!